# How to join all markers with paths in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, path, directory, latitude-longitude

I'm new to Google Maps (API) and I need to get the following result:

[image: paths]

At the moment, I know how to render the map and place markers on it (based on longitude and latitude).

```
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(response[0].latitude, response[0].longitude),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

for (var i = 0; i < response.length; ++i) {

    new google.maps.Marker({
        'map' : map,
        'position' : new google.maps.LatLng(response[i].latitude, response[i].longitude),
        'title' : response[i].address
    });

}
```

Variable `response` structure is like:

```
[
Object
address: "Krišjāņa Barona iela 25, Riga, LV-1011, Latvia"
latitude: "24.1245290"
longitude: "56.9528510"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
address: "Rīgas iela 1, Tukums, Tukuma novads, LV-3101, Latvia"
latitude: "23.1630590"
longitude: "56.9663880"
__proto__: Object
]
```

There could be a lot of markers. I'm looking for a way to join markers with paths like in the preview image.

I don't know for what I should search and I need your help in this, guys. Thanks in an advice!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An example from [Google's tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines):

```
  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
```

Also, see [the reference entry for `Polylines`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline).

If you don't know how to map the response object to an array of `LatLng` objects, here's an example:

```
var flightPath = responseArray.map(function (item) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(item.latitude, item.longitude);
});
```

Comment: I had trouble finding specifics on this as well-- still not clear on your addendum for responseArray. Can you expand?

Comment: Finally you should add this, flightPath.setMap(map);